# External functions: Calling a C script that use external Library

Tags: c, modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to call an external C code that use GLPK (GNU Linear Programming Kit) within my Modelica model. The C code works just fine, have tested it in a stand alone mode where all the inputs are self-supplied. When I tried to link it with my Modelica model, it starts to give me linker-type error, that is similar to below:

```
examples.SimpleSystemOptimalDispatch_functions.c:(.text+0x99d): undefined reference to `glp_set_row_bnds'
```

I notice that to run the C code in a stand alone mode, a special linker has to be used

```
gcc standalonecode.c -lglpk -o standalone
```

I believe the problem is in linking process, but I fail to grasp how to tell Modelica to do the link automatically. Any idea how to solve this linking problem in Modelica?

Thank you and best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

What I did was:

1. Compile the glpk.h located in /usr/local/include/ using

```
gcc -c glpk.h -o libglpk.o
```

2. Using @ReinstateMonica answer, I made my .c file into .so

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -lglpk -o liblinprog.so st_linprog.c
```

3. In my function.mo in my Modelica, I put annotation as follow

```
annotation(Library ={"linprog","glpk"},
           LibraryDirectory="modelica://SolarTherm/Resources/Include/lib");
```

What I understood is that since my st_linprog.c is depending on libglpk, then in order for Modelica to be able to run using libglpk, I have to compile glpk.h and convert st_linprog.c to shared library. During the st_linprog.c conversion into shared library, -lglpk flag makes sure that the shared library is linked to libglpk (I think).

If you guys have more elegant approach kindly share it here! Cheers,

Phil

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use a special linker. The `-lglpk` just told the linker to link your executable with the `glpk` library (`libglpk`).

Now, Modelica has a usability problem - many of them - and the fact that there's no simple way of just telling Modelica "here's my C file, here's my dynamic library I need, have a go at it" is just the harbinger of worse things ahead.

What you have to do instead is to compile your code to a dynamic library, and then this dynamic library will transitively pull in the `libglpk` dependency.

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -lglpk -o libmyCode.so myCode.c
```

Comment: Hi,Many thanks for your reply. I tried to do as you say by running the g++ -fPIC -shared -lglpk -o libmyCode.so myCode.c

But I still get the error from Modelica Message board
 "<U+007F>ELF<U+0002><U+0001><U+0001>" and so on.

I am totally new to this C programming and Modelica, so a bit clueless here. Thanks a lot!